# Updated value with ZIO but the value doesn't persist - Scala

Tags: scala, zio

I have a function to update the log date using ZRef. It does update the value but later when I try to retrieve the value, I don't get the default value. Any ideas why?

Updating value:

```
for {
  env <- ZIO.environment[Logs]
  logsRef <- env.get[Log].datalogs
  _ <- logsRef.update(_.copy(logdate = <some new log date>))
}
yield {
  something
}
```

Retrieving value:

```
for {
  env <- ZIO.environment[Logs]
  logsRef <- env.get.datalogs
  logs <- logsRef.get
  logdate <- logs.logdate //Not updated date
}
yield {
  something
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new environment for each invocation, thus each little program starts with its own ref which is empty. - I am not an expert in **ZIO** but you probably should not create the env but rather ask for it and only create it on the main.

Comment: How can I get/ask for the same environment?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, as I said, I don't use **ZIO**, you probably need to use any other combinator that then produces a final value of type `ZIO[Logs, SomeErrotType, Out]` which then can be combined with other `ZIOs` in the main and then finally provide the env to that one.

Comment: The problem probably lies in the way that you connect these 2 code snippets in your application, but we can't see that part. A self contained reproduction would help. You might even detect the problem yourself while creating one.

Comment: Even without ZIO-specific combinators - you can run `ZIO.environment[Logs]` in `main` and pass `env` as function's argument. Although there is probably some way to achieve that with layers and "magic".